# Unable to flash ESP32 WROVER

Tags: programming, esp32

I designed a PCB with a ESP32-WROVER-E(16MB). I am unable to flash it. The PCB and schematics are given in the following link.

https://oshwlab.com/gadisureshkumar/2021-12-28-iot-now-motor_copy

I had no problem using RX, TX PINS with external USB to serial converter. However I am receiving the following error.

```
A fatal error occurred: MD5 of file does not match data in flash!
```

Complete log is:

```
Warning: Board breadboard:avr:atmega328bb doesn't define a 'build.board' preference. Auto-set to: AVR_ATMEGA328BB
Sketch uses 222717 bytes (16%) of program storage space. Maximum is 1310720 bytes.
Global variables use 16128 bytes (4%) of dynamic memory, leaving 311552 bytes for local variables. Maximum is 327680 bytes.
esptool.py v3.1
Serial port COM4
Connecting........____
Chip is ESP32-D0WD-V3 (revision 3)
Features: WiFi, BT, Dual Core, 240MHz, VRef calibration in efuse, Coding Scheme None
Crystal is 40MHz
MAC: 58:bf:25:eb:e5:e8
Uploading stub...
Running stub...
Stub running...
Changing baud rate to 921600
Changed.
Configuring flash size...
Flash will be erased from 0x0000e000 to 0x0000ffff...
Flash will be erased from 0x00001000 to 0x00005fff...
Flash will be erased from 0x00010000 to 0x00046fff...
Flash will be erased from 0x00008000 to 0x00008fff...
Compressed 8192 bytes to 47...
Writing at 0x0000e000... (100 %)
Wrote 8192 bytes (47 compressed) at 0x0000e000 in 0.0 seconds (effective 2080.5 kbit/s)...
File  md5: e6327541e2dc394ca2c3b3280ac0f39f
Flash md5: 84d04c9d6cc8ef35bf825d51a5277699
MD5 of 0xFF is 84d04c9d6cc8ef35bf825d51a5277699

A fatal error occurred: MD5 of file does not match data in flash!
A fatal error occurred: MD5 of file does not match data in flash!
```

I tried the following but with no use.

```
esptool.py --port COM4 write_flash_status --non-volatile 0
esptool.py v2.8
Serial port COM4
Connecting...
Detecting chip type... ESP32
Chip is ESP32D0WDQ5 (revision 3)
Features: WiFi, BT, Dual Core, 240MHz, VRef calibration in efuse, Coding Scheme None
Crystal is 40MHz
MAC: 58:bf:25:eb:e5:e8
Uploading stub...
Running stub...
Stub running...
Initial flash status: 0x0200
Setting flash status: 0x0000
After flash status:   0x0200
Hard resetting via RTS pin...
```

Also, I performed the following command to receive the complete flash contents in to the file `flash_contents.bin`, which is available [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1RzfORhQiWdDyrYlgI7Zgtg-OgZm4dfZX/view?usp=sharing).

```
esptool.py -b 460800 --port COM4 read_flash 0 0x400000 flash_contents.bin
```

Please direct me in the right direction:

1. I think it is problem with the hardware.
2. If the first point is true, is it because of bad design?
3. If the first point is true, is it because of soldering from the PCB maker?
4. If it is software problem, how can I fix it?

Comment: Yes, its a software problem. Use the software to fix up the defective pcb design. You have skinny power tracks and a torturous top gnd fill.

Comment: Your method of driving the relays is flawed. Powering a 4067 from 3.3V and switching 12V for the relays is going to end in tears. Don’t use a 4067 in this manner.

Comment: @Kartman, I connected 4067 to a driver ULN. They are not directly connected to the relays.

Comment: Electrically that is good, but it is unusual to use a mux as this only allows 1 relay at a time to be activated. More common would be a string of hc595s or tpic6b595 for a more integrated solution. Other suggestions would be to add some input protection - at least some capacitors would give some filtering and ESD résilience.

Comment: @Kartman, Thank you. However, I still have doubt why am I unable to flash my ESP32.

Comment: I gave a suggestion in my first response. Poor pcb design - skinny tracks to the esp32. The esp32 wants a good 3.3V supply of 500mA. Random failure of firmware download suggests your supply is poor. Verify by wiring a good 3.3V source direct to the esp32.